# Prevent loading all images in recycleview inside the nestedscrollview instead of one by one image loading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nestedscrollview

Project contain the main layout with fragment included.
Included fragment contain recycle view inside the "nested scroll view",

I couldn't create multiple recycle view without using nested scroll view
So I am using nested scroll view to view multiple vertical scroll recycle views, but all images are loading at the beginning instead of loading one by one image loading.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: to show multiple vertical scroll list inside the nested scroll view

Comment: all images are loading at beginning instead of one by one

Comment: Have you tried pagination? It will load only specific number of data and will hit API after you scroll at particular position.

Comment: that's how ScrollViews work. You have to use nested recycler view to make it work as you want

Comment: @VladMatvienko. thanks.. But in this case there is no connection between those two listviews but in same page

Comment: I see not a single reason why you can't connect them

Comment: both data are different